# Apache Redirect with subdirectories

Tags: apache, redirect

This is my current setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.product.com
        Redirect "/something" "https://www.anotherredirectwebsite.com.com/something-name-product"        
        RedirectPermanent / https://www.redirectsite.com/

        Include includes/product-config.inc

        # Enable SSL
        Include ssl-conf/product_ssl.conf
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect non-www to wwww
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName product.com
        RedirectPermanent / https://www.product.com/
        Include ssl-conf/product_ssl.conf
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect non-www http to https
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName product.com
        RedirectPermanent / https://www.product.com/
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect www http to https
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.product.com
        Define proxy_host www.product.com
    RedirectPermanent / https://www.product.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I want everyone going to product.com to be redirected to a certain website. However when someone goes to product.com/something I want them to be redirected to a different website.

Problem now is that product.com/anysubdirectory will not be redirected, but the original site is shown. And this also causes the /something to not be redirected as well.

Comment: _a certain website_ and _a different website_ are two different sites or both are `www.redirectsite.com`?

Comment: No, the certain website is redirectwebsite.com. However the different website is anotherredirectwebsite.com

Comment: do you need to configure also `redirectwebsite.com` and `anotherredirectwebsite.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName product.com
    ServerAlias www.product.com
    RedirectPermanent / https://www.product.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName product.com
    ServerAlias www.product.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule     ^something/(.*)          https://www.anotherredirectsite.com/something-name-product/$1  [R=301,L]
    RedirectPermanent / https://www.redirectsite.com/
    # SSL config
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Will this still redirect other subdirectories like: `product.com/about` ??

Comment: `product.com/about` -> `www.redirectsite.com/about` Do you mean that `something` is _any_ directory? Then, of course, `^something/(.*)` is not a solution.

Comment: No the `something` is a particular subdirectie that needs redirecting. However all the other subdirectories apart from `something` needs redirecting to `redirectsite.com`

Comment: Then it works. Did you try? You must, of course, add SSL config data.